# pushing the page content to the side when ( hamburger ) menu is activated

Tags: css, css-transitions, hamburger-menu

When the sidebar menu is activated in [this implementation](http://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Modern-Off-canvas-Accordion-Navigation-With-jQuery-sidenav/), I'd like the page content to get pushed to the side. Currently, that is not happening; the  new content simply appears as an overlay over the page content.

What css instruction am I looking for to make it behave like [this one](http://mac81.github.io/pure-drawer/) where the page content is pushed to the side?

Comment: You just need to update the `padding-left` for the `body`. Have you tried anything?

Comment: Or use transform: translate(<Sidebar width>, 0);